# strip last character from parameter if it is 's'

Tags: macros, strings

I have a semantic annotation `\monster` to annotate mentions of monsters so that they are indexed:

```
\newcommand{\indexMonster}[1]{\index{#1}}
\newcommand{\monster}[1]{#1\indexMonster{#1}}
```

Now, most of the monsters mentions are in plural but some are not. I would like the index entries to be in singular. So I am looking for a way to strip the last character of the `\monster` argument if it is *'s'*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution uses `xstring`. Since there are some terrible monsters named **albatross** which are intesly feared, and you of course will be writing a lot about, I have also made a warning system for when the names of monsters have been changed. You can of course drop this if you feel like. If you want to override the test for monsters ending in `s`, simply add braces around your monster, like in the example below.

**Output**
[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt,draft]{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{ifdraft}
\newcommand{\indexMonster}[1]{\index{#1}}
\newcommand{\monster}[1]{%
    \IfEndWith{#1}{s}{%
    % Do nothing if ends with s.
    \StrGobbleRight{#1}{1}[\result]%
    \result\indexMonster{\result}%
    % Issue a warning on changed monsters
    \ifdraft{%
    \marginpar{Monster \textbf{#1} was changed to \result.}%
    }{}%%
    }{%
    #1\indexMonster{#1}}%
    }
\begin{document}
\monster{Dogs} \monster{Dog} \monster{albatross} \monster{{albatross}}
\end{document}
```

---

### Second solution

Here is my attempt at this with `expl3`. I just did the text-replacement, not the indexing, but that should be trivial.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\monster}{m}
 {
  \l_wilx_monster:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \l_wilx_monster:n
 {
    % Check if last character is "s"
    \str_if_eq_x:nnTF { \str_item:nn {#1} {-1} } {s} 
        % True: print string expect for last string (in other words, remove s)
        {\str_range:nnn {#1} {1} {-2}} %
        % False: Print string as usual
        {#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\monster{dogs}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I do not think this answers the question. However, looking at `xstring`, some combination of the macros could probably give me what I want. I am not clear as to how to compute say string length minus 1 expression to cut the string right.

Comment: Oh, right, I'm sorry, I clearly misunderstood here. My bad. See my edit with new code.

Comment: I am accepting this because it does what the question asks for. Unfortunately, it turns out my case is a little bit more complex. I am going to open a new question using your answer as a starting point.

Comment: yes, I guess it is. I think the best course is just the manual one, looking over every one of them by hand in the end.

Answer (score 9):

Here is an example how to strip the last `s` using TeX primitives. The expandable macro `\striplastS` is created. `\striplastS{texts}` expands to `text` and `\striplastS{text}` expands to `text` too.

```
\def\striplastS#1{\striplastSa{#1}#1\end s\end\eend}
\def\striplastSa#1#2s\end#3\eend{\ifx\end#3\end#1\else#2\fi}

%test:
\message{\striplastS{text} \striplastS{texts}} % prints: text text
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance about TeX, but can you explain how this works? What is the meaning of all those `\end` and `\eend`? I can't seem to find any source that explains the `\eend` command.

Comment: How to test for multiple characters? (`.`, `,`, `!`, and `?` in my case)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `stringstrings`package by Steven B. Segletes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\usepackage{makeidx}\makeindex

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\indexMonster}[1]{%
       \testmatchingchar{#1}{$}{s}
       \ifmatchingchar
          \substring[q]{#1}{1}{$-1}\index{\thestring}
        \else
          \index{#1}
       \fi}
\newcommand{\monster}[1]{#1\indexMonster{#1}}

\monster{zombies}

\pagebreak

\monster{zombie}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have more problems than you think of.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\makeindex[name=monsters,title=Monster index]

\newcommand{\indexMonster}[1]{\index[monsters]{\stripfinals{#1}}}
\newrobustcmd{\monster}[1]{#1\indexMonster{#1}}
\makeatletter % Wipet's
\newcommand{\stripfinals}[1]{\strip@final@s{#1}#1\@nnil s\@nnil\@nil}
\def\strip@final@s#1#2s\@nnil#3\@nil{%
  \ifx\@nnil#3\@nnil#1\else#2\fi
}

% we don't want monster to be indexed also in the table of contents
% or in headers
\newcommand{\fixmonster}{\let\monster\@firstofone}
\patchcmd{\addtocontents}
 {\let}
 {\fixmonster\let}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\makeatletter
\fancyhead[RE]{\fixmonster\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\fixmonster\rightmark}

\newcommand{\WviiSPOT}{\mbox{\monster{*S~P~O~T*}}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{\monster{zombies} and \WviiSPOT}

\monster{asasas}, \monster{zombies} and \WviiSPOT

\clearpage

\monster{zombie} and \monster{uss}

\printindex[monsters]

\end{document}
```

[image]