# indexing woes with macro arguments

Tags: macros, indexing

I have asked [strip last character from parameter if it is 's'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315804/strip-last-character-from-parameter-if-it-is-s) and I was given an answer. However, it turns out my case is little bit more complicated. Some of the monsters have hard to type names so I used a macros, e.g., `\WviiSPOT`, instead of directly typing the monster names. It turns out that combination of indexing and paragraphs fails to compile. Is there a way to make this work?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}

\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\indexMonster}[1]{\index{#1}}
\newcommand{\monster}[1]{%
    \IfEndWith{#1}{s}{%
    \StrGobbleRight{#1}{1}[\result]%
    #1\indexMonster{\result}%
    }{%
    #1\indexMonster{#1}}%
    }

\newcommand{\WviiSPOT}{\mbox{\monster{*S~P~O~T*}}}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
This works:
\monster{Red Pirannhas} \monster{Bambiphoots} \monster{Stag Weevils} \WviiSPOT{}

This does not:
\paragraph{But \WviiSPOT{} is insane!}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\newcommand`.

Comment: @Manuel: For which of the commands?

Comment: All of them could be, but the “important” are `\monster` and `\indexMonster`, since the other one is just a shortcut.

Comment: @Manuel: Thank you. That seems to solve the issue.

Comment: Glad this worked out. By the way, I think you added the wrong question in your url.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the indexing macros, except that they're fragile. Just use `\DeclareRobustCommand{\monster}{...}` or use `\protect` in front of the command when in moving arguments. Beware that if you have a monster name in a section title and you compile the table of contents, you'll get an entry in the index referring to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my answer [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315820/53956), including the new command. You just have to `\protect` it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\usepackage{makeidx}\makeindex

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\indexMonster}[1]{%
      \testmatchingchar{#1}{$}{s}
      \ifmatchingchar
          \substring[q]{#1}{1}{$-1}\index{\thestring}
        \else
          \index{#1}
       \fi}
\newcommand{\monster}[1]{#1\indexMonster{#1}}

\monster{zombies}

\newcommand{\WviiSPOT}{\mbox{\monster{*S~P~O~T*}}}

\WviiSPOT

\pagebreak

\paragraph{But \protect\WviiSPOT is insane!}

\monster{zombie}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `strinstrings` package by Steven B. Segletes.